# Редирект регистрационной формы wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Если возникает ошибка при заполнении регистрационной формы на wordpress то меня перекидывает на стандартную форму регистрации вордпресс, а мне надо, чтобы пользователь оставался на моей странице и ошибки выводились на мою страницу. Из всего что я знаю, это редирект после успешной регистрации делается вот так

```
function otfm_my_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url('/');
}
add_filter('url_after_register_rcl', 'otfm_my_registration_redirect',10);
```

Но как сделать чтобы на процесс ошибки я мог поставить редирект?

Comment: В WordPress нет такого фильтра `url_after_register_rcl`. Поясните, к какому плагину/теме относится ваш вопрос.

Comment: @KAGG Design нет у меня никакго плагина это чисто wordpress советую почитать!

Comment: Советую поискать такую строку в исходном коде WordPress, а потом уже восклицать.

Comment: Я за вас уже нашел все в Сети. У вас установлен плагин WP Recall. У него есть вызов такого фильтра в строке 135 файла /functions/register.php. Так что прежде чем агрессивно спорить, стоит разобраться, какие плагины у вас установлены.

Comment: @KAGG Design первый раз слышу о таком плагине, вам показать список моих установленных плагинов??

Comment: Если WP Recall не установлен, то код, который вы привели, бессмысленный. Выполняться он не будет.